# Scan/Match incorrect input error messages

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to count the correct inputs from the user. An input looks like:

```
m = "<ex=1>test xxxx <ex=1>test xxxxx test <ex=1>"
```

The tag `ex=1` and the word `test` have to be connected and in this particular order to count as correct. In case of an invalid input, I want to send the user an error message that explains the error.

I tried to do it as written below:

```
ex_test_size = m.scan(/<ex=1>test/).size  # => 2
test_size = m.scan(/test/).size  # => 3
ex_size = m.scan(/<ex=1>/).size  # => 3

puts "lack of tags(<ex=1>)" if ex_test_size < ex_size
puts "Lack of the word(test)" if ex_test_size < test_size
```

I believe it can be written in a better way as the way I wrote, I guess, is prone to errors. How can I make sure that all the errors will be found and shown to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [negative lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
#⇒ ["xxx test", "<ex=1>"]
m.scan(/<ex=1>(?!test).{,4}|.{,4}(?<!<ex=1>)test/).map do |msg|
  "<ex=1>test expected, #{msg} got"
end.join(', ')
```

We scan the string for either `<ex=1>` not followed by `test` or vice versa. Also, we grab up to 4 characters that violate the rule for the more descriptive message.